Can i tell devpi to cache a list of packages?
I want to use devpi as an extra package cache because our main JFrog Artifactory sometimes goes down and I my airflow with PythonVirtualenvOperators should work even in these cases.
I want to do the following:

set --index-url to our main Artifactory and --extra-index-url to devpi: so that the package will be downloaded from main Artifactory when it's possible.
somehow tell devpi that the requirements.txt that I pass to PythonVirtualenvOperator should be cached into my devpi (and all their dependencies should be cached too).

Can it be done?
